# How to decode JSON starting with "[" using swift Codable Protocol

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have encountered a JSON response from a server and need to handle it.

Basically, the root level of the JSON is an array instead of a dictionary. For example:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Joe",
    "age": 50
  },
]
```

I have build a struct conforming to Codable:

```
struct response: Codable {
    let responseArray: [Person]
}

struct person: Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
        case age = "age"
    }
}
```

I get the following error when trying to decode it:

```
▿ DecodingError
  ▿ typeMismatch : 2 elements
    - .0 : Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>
    ▿ .1 : Context
      - codingPath : 0 elements
      - debugDescription : "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead."
      - underlyingError : nil
```

Is there a way to handle the array using coding keys if it is not named?

If not, how would one handle this situation?

Comment: Show your call to `decode`.

Comment: Arrays aren't "named," I think you're thinking of dictionaries and their keys.

Comment: Well I tried the most obvious thing to get this working and surprise! it worked:

I tried to decode [person].self instead of response.

Comment: @DavidChopin you are right. I will edit my question to be more specific about the response not being a dictionary.

Comment: start struct names with capital letter also here you don't need `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {`

Comment: @rmaddy This is what I had:

`let response = try decoder.decode(response.self, from: data)`

As I mentioned above, I tried the most obvious thing (decoding an array of person instead of making a response struct) and that worked.

I feel dumb now. I guess coding for 12 hours every day this week to complete this Udacity assignment has fried my brain...

Comment: @Xaxxus That should be in your question, not in a comment. Please [edit].

Comment: @rmaddyi should clarify, I tried the above shortly after creating this post and found that it worked. As such, I marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the json is an array do deocde should be `[Person].self` You can try

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int  
}
```

```
let res = try? JSONDecoder().deocde([Person].self,from:data)
print(res)
```